# Call static member from inherited class instance

Tags: c++, static, static-methods, static-members

I have two classes, `Y` and `X`, and `Y` holds some static members -- which I'm trying to access via an `X` instance:

```
template <class T>
class Y {
public:
    Y() {
        i = 0;
        v = std::vector<int>(10, 10);
    }
    static int value() {
        return v[i];
    }
private:
    static int i;
    static std::vector<int> v;
};

class X : public Y<X> {
public:
    X() {
    }
};

int main() {
    X *x(new X());
    std::cout << x->value() << std::endl;
}
```

Even though it compiles, it does not link correctly:

```
$ g++ t.cpp
/tmp/ccB4ijzw.o: In function `Y<X>::Y()':
t.cpp:(.text._ZN1YI1XEC2Ev[Y<X>::Y()]+0x11): undefined reference to `Y<X>::i'
t.cpp:(.text._ZN1YI1XEC2Ev[Y<X>::Y()]+0x4a): undefined reference to `Y<X>::v'
/tmp/ccB4ijzw.o: In function `Y<X>::value()':
t.cpp:(.text._ZN1YI1XE5valueEv[Y<X>::value()]+0x6): undefined reference to `Y<X>::i'
t.cpp:(.text._ZN1YI1XE5valueEv[Y<X>::value()]+0x10): undefined reference to `Y<X>::v'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

**Context** (if it matters):

I'm trying to write a memory manager -- `class Y` -- that statically holds a pool of memory, so that all the instances of a `class X` use memory blocks provided by `Y`.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach on what I'm trying to do, but was the somewhat most elegant way I thought of so far. Any ideas are very much welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static data members have to be defined as well as declared. If this was an ordinary class you'd do it like this:

```
// header:
class C {
    static int i;
};

// source:
int C::i = 3;
```

With a class template you don't ordinarily put the code in a source file, so you'd do this:

```
// header:
template <class T>
class C {
    static int i;
};

template <class T>
int C<T>::i = 3;
```

Comment: Ah, that's it, then. I didn't know that; thank you very much! Just another question. Since I have more than two members, is there any suitable syntax that allows *multiple definitions* -- instead of keep repeating `template <class T>`? Anyway, it works perfectly!

Comment: @Rubens - no that I know of. But it's just a couple of keystrokes to copy and paste the line.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function `value` is static it is common to all instances of `class Y`. The way to call a static member function is like

```
std::cout << Y<X>::value() << std::endl;
```

NOT (this is not illegal but it is just not a good practice. Why make the function static i you are going to do this anyway?.)

```
std::cout << x->value() << std::endl;
```

In addition you have to define all the static members. Something like

```
template <class T>
int Y<T>::i = 0;

template <class T>
std::vector<int> Y<T>::v(0);
```

Comment: I recall seeing a question where the OP asks if it should be *forbidden* to access members via instances, and the answer states that it is not. (It wasn't I to down vote your post, anyway).

Comment: It is not illegal to access them through instances. But if you are going to do that why make the function static after all? It is to signify the fact that it belongs to the class not the instances.

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing that is was not forbidden -- since a saw a post saying this while trying to solve my problem.